# How do I convert type string to text in Unity3D?

Tags: string, text, unity-game-engine

I am trying to convert type string to text and I have this error:

"An object reference is required to access non-static member `UIInput.text'"

How do I solve it?

This is my code:

```
 UIInput.text = DB.getName(LoginSystem.userNameStatic)();
 UIInput.text = DB.getPassword ("password");
```

Comment: Are you using Unity's JavaScript, or C#? You are trying to access a static `UIInput` instead of a defined variable. Perhaps try `GetComponent(UIInput).text = ...`?

Comment: I am using C#! Yes I think I am accessing a static UIInput instead of a defined variable.

Comment: so I should put it like this? GetComponent(UIInput).text =  DB.getName(LoginSystem.userNameStatic)(); ?

Comment: I just added that and changed to it and it has an error.

Comment: @Sarah From the various questions you've been asking, I gather that you seem to have problems with C# on a very fundamental level. I would highly recommend you pick up a good book on C# and read through it. It would make issues like this, and the error messages you get, so much easier to understand and solve.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a C# guru but I imagine something like this might work:

```cs
public UIInput uiInput = GetComponent<UIInput>();
uiInput.text = DB.getName(LoginSystem.userNameStatic)();
uiInput.text = DB.getPassword ("password");
```

Basically you want to define your game object's UIInput as a variable, and then you'll be able to set its `text` value.

This is, of course, assuming you have added a UIInput component to your game object.

Also maybe check out these resources:

- http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/scripting/getcomponent
- http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/31958/i-cant-understand-the-syntax-of-getcomponent-in-c.html